# Docker Plesk Yii2 MongoDB connection issue

Tags: php, mongodb, docker, yii2, connection

I have a connection problem between Docker and Yii2 MongoDB on my VPS.

I'm using a VPS with Plesk Onyx. I've created Mongo Docker container and Mongo-express Docker container to easily manage my MongoDB.

The problem comes out when I try to connect, by PHP 'mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb', my web app (built in yii2 MongoDB) to MongoDB, there's no errors but it seems that it can't connect to the db I want. I tried different connection for example MongoDB Atlas in sandbox mode from VPS and all is OK!

What might be the problem, or how can I debug this?

Comment: Find the IP address of your docker database (docker ps - then docker inspect <container name> | grep IPAddress) and use that IP address instead of localhost.

Comment: are you using a docker-compose file? if yes you should post it. If not, it'd make sense to see how you start the docker containers

Comment: I've done what you said @NigelRen but this not solve!

Comment: Can you add your docker compose file or your docker file for the database container

Comment: @Stefano no, i don't use a docker-compose file, i'm using Docker through Plesk where you can find and install easily containers, they run automatically after installation! I don't have connection errors in fact the connection is made, but Yii2 can not interact with the right db.

Comment: @NigelRen, I don't know how to do, where can i find the docker file? Is this docker inspect <container name>? thanks!

Comment: maybe you should replace localhost by your mongodb docker address